# Saving pictures for iphone and android from Photoshop

Tags: iphone, android, photoshop

Saving pictures for use in iPhone and Android applications is a real bore.

Having to make 2 separate versions for iPhone is tedious enough and then creating 3/4 versions for android (or more) is just as difficult.

Is there no way to make one set of pictures in photoshop and have them save in the various formats and sizes for iphone and android?

For instance creating them at the highest resolution necessary and it does all the resizing and such automatically (as if you were to change the image size).

Or am I really going to have to refactor each and every image in my apps?!

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Adobe Device Central and actions/macros in Photoshop may help you to solve your task.

Comment: Macros will definitely help. That's how I did it.